# IMAP/Dovecot sync drafts folder between mail clients

Tags: dovecot, outlook, imap

I don't understand how different mail clients work with the mails inside the drafts folder. Firstly the Gmail and Outlook android app doesn't sync any drafts at all despite I selected the drafts folder in the outlook app (I think the gmail app doesn't offers such a feature). Now I downloaded "K-9 Mail" and selected the drafts folder. It syncs the drafts and I can edit them. But after I edited a draft inside K-9 app the Outlook for Windows can't edit them. The drafts show up in the drafts folder but as received email such as described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1400627/how-to-edit-mail-from-drafts-folder-created-with-k9). Though in Thunderbird I can edit them. Is there a way to fix that with dovecot or is it the responsibility of the mail clients?

`namespace inbox` section from `doveconf -n`:

```
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location =
  mailbox Drafts {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Spam {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix =
}
```

Comment: If you run `doveconf -n` what is the content of the `namespace inbox` section?

Comment: I updated my question and added the `namespace inbox` section

Comment: Yours looks the same as mine, but I've not tested editing drafts from multiple different clients... was wondering about the `special_use` option for each, looks correct from what I can tell

Comment: as described K9 mail(android) and thunderbird(windows) work great together but outlook on windows does something different and the outlook and gmail android app do not work anyway

Answer (score 0):

According to [this case](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/61deec21-e028-4ab2-93c9-1f9c6eeff0c3/draft-folder-not-sync-all-other-folders-are-working-fine?forum=Exch2016CM), As for Outlook, first you need to be running in either O365 or on an onprem Exchange 2016 environment. Second, you'll need an EAS client that supports syncing the drafts folder, referring to this [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2015/06/08/announcing-exchange-activesync-v16/) And are you aim to sync email drafts between K-9 and Outlook?

Comment: I thought there is a solution working for every mail client. Actually I wanted to use the gmail or outlook android app but these two do not even sync the drafts at all. K9 Mail(android) and Thunderbird(windows) work fine together. But what if I give access to somebody else and this person is only familial (or wants to use) outlook for windows and the gmail android app. I just like it if everything is working as it should.

Comment: But it sounds like that this is an issue on the client side and I can't solve it with dovecot. Am I right?

Comment: Sorry but I'm not quite familiar with dovecot and maybe you are right.